# Bootstrap form divided into 2 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the following look of the page: [picture](http://shrani.si/f/1U/3B/2QY0vKGp/untitled.png). So far I set the form class to container, as child of that set one row div for the entire form and as child of that two `col-md-6` divs in which I wish to have form groups.

My goal is to make some inputs to appear on the left side and some on the right. However so far nothing seems to move my html as expected. Can someone provide quick code how to properly organize the divs?

My code (don't mind the php it is just a helper in Codeigniter):

```
<div class="admin-box">
<h3>Title</h3>
<?php echo form_open_multipart($this->uri->uri_string(), array('class' =>" container", 'id'=>"ajax-upload")); ?>
<fieldset>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">

        <div class="control-group <?php echo form_error('name') ? 'error' : ''; ?>">
            <?php echo form_label('Name', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
            <div class='controls'>
                <input id='athletes_name' type='text' name='athletes_name' maxlength="255" value="" />
                <span class='help-inline'><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">

        <div class="control-group <?php echo form_error('name') ? 'error' : ''; ?>">
            <?php echo form_label('Name', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
            <div class='controls'>
                <input id='athletes_name' type='text' name='athletes_name' maxlength="255" value="" />
                <span class='help-inline'><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i can see that ur code is working. http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8695/embedded/result/ isnt this what you wanted ?

Comment: yes but if you shrink the window it jumps down and moves, I want it to be fixed on the right side no matter what. My page is not so wide and the content always stays under each other

Comment: btw, control-group is an old BS2 class, i believe… looks like your markup straddles versions 2 and 3…

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="admin-box container">
<h3>Title</h3>
<?php echo form_open_multipart($this->uri->uri_string(), array('class' =>" container", 'id'=>"ajax-upload")); ?>
<fieldset>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">

        <div class="control-group <?php echo form_error('name') ? 'error' : ''; ?>">
            <?php echo form_label('Name', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
            <div class='controls'>
                <input id='athletes_name' type='text' name='athletes_name' maxlength="255" value="" />
                <span class='help-inline'><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">

        <div class="control-group <?php echo form_error('name') ? 'error' : ''; ?>">
            <?php echo form_label('Name', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
            <div class='controls'>
                <input id='athletes_name' type='text' name='athletes_name' maxlength="255" value="" />
                <span class='help-inline'><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer looks OK, but, please, care to add at least 1-2 lines of comments. Stack Overflow is build upon good quality questions and answers. Pure-code-only answer isn't a good quality answers at all.

Comment: sorry, I'm from china , althoug I register stack have a long time,but this is my first answer, because my english is not very good, so i don't want to say too much.

Comment: :] Your English is far better than many here! Speak as much as you can, if you only have anything valuable to say. If you make any error, others will try to correct this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try more

Answer (score 0):

Use the smallest column definition `col-xs-6` instead. The grid behavior will display horizontally at all times.

By default `col-md-6` will display the columns under each other on devices with (screen) widths smaller than 992px and display them horizontally above.